# multiplying a column by another if it is the same year

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, one is sampled monthly, the other is sampled yearly with datetime index.

I want to multiply the values from a column in the monthly dataframe by the value from a column in the yearly dataframe if it is the same year. How can I do that?

Thank you very much for your help,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]}, index=['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-02'])
df.index=  pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df
            column1
2018-01-01        1
2018-01-02        1
2018-01-03        1
2019-01-03        2
2019-01-02        2

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'columnX' : [2, 3]}, index=['2018', '2019']) 
df2.index=  pd.to_datetime(df2.index)    

df2

            columnX
2018-01-01        2
2019-01-01        3
```

Expected result:

```
df
              Column1  Results
    2018-01-01    1        2
    2018-01-02    1        2
    2018-01-03    1        2
    2019-01-03    2        6
    2019-01-02    2        6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative solution using `numpy`:

```
s = df2.assign(x=df2.index.year).set_index('x')['columnX']
df['Result'] = np.vectorize(s.get)(df.index.year) * df['column1'].values

print(df)

            column1  Result
2018-01-01        1       2
2018-01-02        1       2
2018-01-03        1       2
2019-01-03        2       6
2019-01-02        2       6
```

Comment: This way of doing it is much faster! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
In [57]: df = (df.assign(y=df.index.year)
    ...:         .merge(df2.assign(y=df2.index.year), how='left')
    ...:         .eval("Results = column1 * columnX")
    ...:         .drop(['columnX','y'],1)
    ...:         .set_index(df.index))
    ...:
    ...:

In [58]: df
Out[58]:
            column1  Results
2018-01-01        1        2
2018-01-02        1        2
2018-01-03        1        2
2019-01-03        2        6
2019-01-02        2        6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer that works! Is there a way to create the Results column directly in the original dataframe? I need to perform other calculations after that. Someting like: `df['Results']= ...` I basically need to keep the the original datetime index of df untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
df2.index = df2.index.map(lambda x: x.year)
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda y: y['column1'] * df2['columnX'][y.name.year], axis=1)
```

Comment: Note that `pd.DataFrame.apply` isn't magic, it's actually very inefficient as it is performing a calculation in a loop row-wise. For larger dataframes you can use, for example, MaxU's solution.